# Solutions to the problem of the US's strong offensive capabilities incentivising potential adversaries to create 'buffers'?

Tags: armed-conflict, united-nations, geopolitics

The US has great reach with very destructive conventional weapons, particularly aircraft carriers and their entourage, which can sit off an enemy coastline and pummel a large landmass indefinitely.

Since potential adversaries are well aware of this capability, they naturally prepare strategies against it, like Russia's [S-400](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-400_missile_system) Anti-Aircraft missile system, and China's [DF-21](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DF-21) anti-ship missiles.

Another way of reducing the potential threat of aircraft carriers could be to seek a buffer of at least 200km from their shores.

Both China and Russia could be argued to be considering attempting expanding their 'buffer'.

#### Question

Noting that many innovative solutions were successfully floated, explored, and eventually implemented to reduce the risk/threat of [Mutually Assured Destruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_assured_destruction#Early_Cold_War) during the cold war, and since an invasion by one country into another to create a 'buffer' would come at a great cost of life, and assuming the US could not easily be convinced to outright reduce its attack capability (since it would almost certainly not be in its interests to do so), have any other ideas been floated to try to avoid creating pressure on the US's potential adversaries to take land/seas around their own nation?

Comment: A 200km buffer from the ocean for the purpose of defence against aircraft carriers is just land you don't care as much if the US bombs it, rather than if they bomb your core territory. But if another country's land would serve as such a buffer, surely you're better off not conquering it; if you don't own it then you care **even less** if the US bombs it. Conquering it will only move your borders closer to the aircraft carriers, not further away.

Comment: @Ben true, but I’m thinking more of land or seas that are US neutral or US allied, eg Ukraine or Taiwan (theoretically absolutely anywhere else too, just that those two come immediately to mind).

Comment: Conquering buffer land works as a defence against forces that need land-based infrastructure relatively close to you to attack. Now your opponent has to start a war and invade and hold the buffer land *before* they can start building that infrastructure, instead of building it up before the war. It doesn't help defend against "great reach with very destructive conventional weapons, particularly aircraft carriers and their entourage", since those great-reach weapons don't need nearby land-based infrastructure. So countering that one particular incentive isn't something you need to worry about.

Comment: You seem to be interested in a more general issue than specifically potential US adversaries' incentive to rewrite borders to put 200km of land between themselves and a potential aircraft carrier; I merely suggest you edit your question to more clearly ask about what you're actually interested in.

Comment: Restructuring international governance in a global one-person-one-vote format, and jailing every world leader responsible for bombing civilians in the past 20 years, would probably do it

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the premise of your question is dodgy, especially when it comes to the role to aircraft carriers. Conquering a buffer state does not reduce the distance between international waters and the political, industrial, and military centers of gravity of a great power. At most, it would deny the carrier battle group the ability to *legally* enter the territorial waters of the coastal state before the hostilities start. I don't believe anybody would be silly enough to operate warships within a dozen miles of the shore if they can help it. (Straits like the Bosporus are a different matter. Who controls them is critical for Russia.)

If you look back at precedents like the 1991 Gulf War, the *"American Way of War"* against a regional power is to build up **ground bases** for the Army and Air Force in allied regional countries. The Navy is critical in the early, defensive phase of a war, but going on the offensive requires heavy ground forces and well-supplied airbases.

Even so, the US has learned that it may be able to *punish* regional powers, or *change* unpopular regimes, but it cannot *install* a government of their choice. They couldn't do it to 40 million Iraqis or 40 million Afghans, and they didn't try it against 83 million Iranians, despite persistent hostile relations.

So how to counter this *"American Way of War"* as a regional power?

- Have a population that can be *trusted* to stand with the government even if government operations are disrupted. Nationalism may help in this regard. So might religion, if the nation is unified.
- Have a government that will *reorganize* along the same political lines after a decapitation strike. The American public might personalize things, but hopefully the American government knows better these days (post Rumsfeld).
- Have an armed force to make life hell for an invader.

How about a peer or near-peer competitor? All that and:

- Diversify import and export partners.
- Prepare for being cut out of US-dominated financial systems.
- Air defenses to prevent punitive/coercive strikes.